# Installed Wrong Nvidia Drivers

Tags: arch-linux, drivers, nvidia

I'm running Arch 3.17, and last night I tried to install drivers for Nvidia, which has caused my system to go to a shell on boot. [This](http://pastebin.com/SUyALH7e) is the output of /var/log/pacman.log Around

```
[2014-11-19 22:36] [PACMAN] Running 'pacman -S lib32-mesa-demos'
```

Is where I began installing drivers. After a few reboots of installing different ones, and seeing which one would make TF2 work, my computer eventually got to the point where it is now. Which drivers are in conflict with each other? Or are there config files that were messed up in the process? Any direction or help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: by Arch 3.17, you mean Arch with the 3.17 kernel?

Comment: Yes, sorry. 3.17.3-1-ARCH.

Answer (score 0):

I just 'fixed' it myself, actually. All I did was follow the install guide for the Nouveau drivers and it fixed itself.
[Here is where I found this.](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/nouveau)